# Listview Refill Problems (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a problem when I want to refill my listview.
Everything is working perfectly for the first time, but when I go back into the form for a 2th time, and it has to repopulate the listview, then it won't work.
The weird thing is that my list of listviews doesn't get changed, so it remains populated with the exact same items, and I don't change anything.

I did some debugging, and I found that only the index is different.

This is an example of the 1st (working) build:

?General.listviewgebieden {System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem)}

```
Capacity: 4
Count: 3
```

?General.listviewgebieden.Item(0) {Text = "ELDC"}

```
BackColor: {System.Drawing.Color}
Checked: False
Focused: False
ForeColor: {System.Drawing.Color}
ImageIndex: -1
Index: -1
ListView: Nothing
Selected: False
SubItems: {System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection}
Tag: Nothing
Text: "ELDC"
```

And this is from the 2th populating:

> ?General.listviewgebieden {System.Collections.Generic.List(Of
>   System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem)}
>
> ```
> Capacity: 4
> Count: 3
> ```

?General.listviewgebieden.Item(0) {Text = "ELDC"}

> ```
> BackColor: {System.Drawing.Color}
> Checked: False
> Focused: False
> ForeColor: {System.Drawing.Color}
> ImageIndex: -1
> Index: 0
> ListView: {System.Windows.Forms.ListView}
> Selected: False
> SubItems: {System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection}
> Tag: Nothing
> Text: "ELDC"
> ```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Gert

Comment: please define "it won't work" - what does it do or not do?

Comment: Hi Plutonix,

I don't see any checkboxes.
So my first 'load' is loading all my checkboxes correctly, while if I return to that page, suddenly my checkboxes are gone, I just see a blank listview.

The rest of the info is in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search we finally found the problem.

The problem wasn't with the listview but with the list of listviewitems.
After the first load of my screen, the list was bound with the listview, and a 2th attempt to populate the listview resulted in a failure, although the listview was empty, the binding in the list was still there.

Since there appeared to be no option to remove the binding link in the list, I had to clear my list, and had it repopulated, in order to work again.